# Can I use ANOVA when participants choose yes/no to a four option IV?

Tags: anova, binary-data

I have one IV with four levels. Participants are asked if they prefer:

Option 1. yes/no 
Option 2. yes/no 
Option 3 yes/no 
and 
Option 4 yes/no.

So, this is a binary response, and as I understand you can't use ANOVA on a yes/no response. However, does it make a difference that each participant answers all four options? Is ANOVA a valid analysis to use?

If not ANOVA, then what can I use? Ordinal logistic regression has been suggested to me, but I can't see "Preference" yes/no as a predictor variable?

Comment: chi square goodness of fit or something along those lines?

Comment: What do you want to inquire? Do you want to compare groups of participants? Or do you want to know if different options are preferred differently? Generally, ANOVA is not useful since ANOVA requires normally distributed data.

Comment: So ANOVA is not useful because it's not possible to get normally distributed data with a yes/no response? I'm not comparing different groups of participants. I'm asking the one group to state their preference for four options. In hindsight it's a design flaw of my study I think, but too late now. I need to analyse it correctly as its come.

Comment: If I can ask one more question...why do you think someone would recommend ordinal logistic regression for this situation? I would be happy to do the chi square, as you suggested Kamster, but am confused by the suggestion of the olr.

Comment: To get more useful responses, you should state the full research problem.  Without that it is difficult to give advice! It seems yo have four Qs, each with a yes/no response. So some multivariate model could be used, like multivariate probit/logit.  Do you also have covariables?  How many? Of what nature?